# Is object created without new operator deleted in a specific case in C++

Tags: c++, object, new-operator

If we have the following code snippet:

```
MyObject my_object = MyObject(0);
my_object = MyObject(1);
```

What happens to MyObject(0)? Is it deleted? Looking at what I have read about it it should only be deleted when we leave the scope of creation, so the anwser is probably no. If this is the case is there any way to explicitly delete it other than using pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `delete` has a special meaning in C++, so the use of *deleted* is unfortunate.

```
MyObject my_object = MyObject(0);
```

This line declares that an object of type `MyObject` created with automatic storage duration (ie, on the stack). This object will be destructed (ie, its destructor will be executed) when the scope ends. No provision is made in the Standard for the recollection of the associated memory (see later example).

This object of type `MyObject` will be constructed using the expression `MyObject(0)`. This constructor will initialize the memory that has been set apart for its exclusive use.

*Note: actually, a temporary could be created and the copy constructor then called, but most compiler eschew this intermediate step, thankfully, as the Standard specifically allows it.*

```
my_object = MyObject(1);
```

This line assigns a new value, determined by the expression `MyObject(1)`, to the already existing `my_object` object. To do so, a temporary of type `MyObject` is created with automatic storage duration. Then, the assignment operator is executed; if not overloaded it will copy the state of the temporary into `my_object`, erasing what previous state was there. At the end of the expression, the temporary is destructed (once again, no provising is made for the recollection of the associated memory).

*Note: `MyObject(0)` is not "deleted", as it does not exist, instead the memory it had written its state to is reused to copy the state from `MyObject(1)`.*

---

As promised, since this seems your worry, a discussion on the memory aspects. This is compiler specific, but most compilers do behave similarly.

Suppose that we have the following function:

```
void f() {
  MyObject my_object = MyObject(0);

  {
    my_object = MyObject(1);
    do_something(my_object);
  }

  {
    my_object = MyObject(2);
    do_something(my_object);
  }
}
```

How much space does it require on the stack ?

- We assume that it performs direct construction on the first line
- We assume the compiler not smart enough to perform Stack Coloring (Clang does not, for example)

With those assumption, it requires the space for 3 `MyObject`.

- `MyObject my_object = MyObject(0);`: `my_object` need live until the end of the function
- `my_object = MyObject(1);`: a temporary need be created
- `my_object = MyObject(2);`: a temporary need be created

The stack space is recollected at the end of the function execution.

If the compiler was smart enough to perform Stack Coloring, then the two temporaries (that are never needed together) could use the same memory spot, thus lowering the space requirement to 2 `MyObject`.

A smart optimizer could also, possibly, directly build `MyObject(1)` and `MyObject(2)` directly into `my_object` (if it can prove that the effects would be the same than building a temporary and then copying it), thus lowering the space requirement to 1 `MyObject`.

Finally, if the definition of `do_something` is visible, and it does not use its parameter, then under certain conditions it could (in theory) completely bypass the construction of `my_object`. Such optimizations can be witness with simple programs like:

```
int main() { int i = 0; for (; i < 1000; ++i); return i; }
```

which are trivially optimized to:

```
int main() { return 1000; }
```

(Note how `i` disappeared)

As you may notice... it's actually very hard to guess what the compiler/optimizer will be able to do. If you really have tight memory requirements, then (perhaps surprisingly), your best bet might be to replace the blocks by functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
MyObject my_object = MyObject(0);
```

This line creates `my_object` on the stack using `MyObject`'s constructor that can accept an `int`.

```
my_object = MyObject(1);
```

This line creates a *temporary* MyObject, again, using the same constructor as the first. This is then assigned to `my_object` by calling the assignment operator. If you didn't provide this operator then the compiler will make one for you that performs a *shallow* copy. When this statement completes, the temporary MyObject goes out of scope and the destructor for it is called.

When your `my_object` goes out of scope it is in turn destroyed in the same fashion. At no point do you need to manually delete this because everything is allocated on the stack.

Comment: So just to check if I understand you correctly, we are creating suma sumarum 3 instances of MyObject class, two of which are going to be deleted after execution of second line (in the end, not directly caused by)?

Comment: @nivwus Actually, in the example you presented, only 2 objects should be created. This is because the compiler is smart enough to see that a `my_object` is being created so it can avoid making an extra temporary object. Basically, the first line is the same as if you had done: `MyObject my_object(0);`.

Comment: I disagree, I think it's highly compiler-dependent. With no optimizations at least, 3 objects are created and destroyed.

Comment: @Luch While in theory 3 objects could be created, in practice that's not what really happens. I've tested this on quite a few compilers including msvc2010, c++ builder2007, gcc-4.5.2, digital mars compiler, and Clang and in all cases the copy constructor is never called -- that intermediate step is always eschew. Just for kicks, I tested this on C++Builder6 as well(a toolchain that's almost 10 years old) and no extra 3rd object was created either. And yes, debugging was on and optimization disabled in all cases.

Comment: At any rate, I don't think this was worth a downvote. The material presented in my answer is correct and, as far as the OP is considered, any compiler he's using will do this. You'd be hard-pressed to find any c++ compilers that doesn't.

Comment: It's not the copy constructor that should get called, but the assignment operator.

Comment: @Luc I'm not sure I follow where you have the disagreement -- which part of my answer do you find inaccurate? The assignment op is only involved in the second line, not the first.

Comment: I've tested this and it also doesn't get called (neither the assignment nor the copy constructor). I have read about this but never bothered to actually test it. While I still think it is dependent on the compiler, I can see you're right on this one. If you edit your answer, I'll be able to change my vote. (SO doesn't let me do it now since more than 1 hour has passed)

Comment: That's ok, I'm glad it's straightened out though.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main regions in memory when talking about newly created objects: the stack and the heap. The heap contains all objects created dynamically with new. These objects need to be explicitly deleted with the delete operator. The stack is scope-specific and all objects defined on the stack will be deleted automatically. Since you don't use new, all your objects will be destroyed when their scope ends.

Assuming no compiler optimizations, your code roughly translates to:

```
{
   MyObject my_object;
   MyObject tempObject0(0);
   my_Object = tempObject0;
   MyObject tempObject1(1);
   my_Object = tempObject;
}//3 objects are deleted by this point (in theory)
```

Also note the difference between

```
MyObject myObject(0);
```

and

```
MyObject myObject = MyObject(0);
```

The second case creates a temporary object, so it will be less efficient. This all of course assuming no optimizations. Depending on the compiler, it might translate to the same thing.

Comment: `// 3 Objects are deleted here` is wrong. Temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression containing them, not at the exit of the containing block. Therefore, `MyObject(0)` is destroyed before `MyObject(1)` is created.

Answer (score 1):

1st line is creating an temp object and this object is assigned to my_object.
In 2nd line, a temporary object is created and it is assigned to my_object.

So there is only one object my_object

We need not to think about temporay object. It is compiler responsibility to handle temporary object.

Comment: OK, Sounds good, so is compiler actually deleting it? I don't want memery leak?

Comment: Memory leak happens if memory allocated from heap is not freed. Here the memory for temporary object is allocated from stack. So u need not worry about memory leak

Comment: So I am actually doing an algorithmic problem with memory limit. If that piece of memerory wouldn'y be free I would actually have O(n lg n) memory instead O(n), which would make my solution fail.

Comment: @nivwusquorum: Compilers nowadays are actually very good at this, especially in optimized builds. This is why it's hard to debug optimzied code: memory is aggressively recycled.